# JavaScript - Add to Class Assignment After Class Initiation

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, ecmascript-6

I am trying to manipulate an already initialised JavaScript class. The class is a http request library and I am trying to create a "base" initiation that will meet all my HTTP request needs, then be able to extend the initialised JavaScript class at the individual request layer. An example would be:

```
const Request = require('my-library');

const requestBaseConnection = new Request(
  {
    httpsProxy: (process.env.HTTPS_PROXY ? process.env.HTTPS_PROXY : ''),
    retryOptions: {
      retries: 0,
      retryableMethods: ['GET', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
      statusShouldRetry: (status) => (status >= 500) && (status <= 599),
    },
    timeout: 100000,
  }
);

const jenkinsServicesDevAxway = () => {

  const token = 'abc';
  const url = 'https://url.com';

  let requestSpecifics = { headers: {'X-API-Key': `${token}`}, baseURL: `${url}` };

  const connection = { ... requestBaseConnection, ...requestSpecifics };

  return connection
};


module.exports = {
  jenkinsServicesDevAxway
};
```

As you can see I thought this is whee the JavaScript Spread operator would maybe help me? As I thought it would concatenate the two objects together. It doesn't seem to be working thought as when I `console.log(connection)` I get `Connection: [object Object]`.

What I would hope for would be it would add the:

```
{ headers: {'X-API-Key': `${token}`}, baseURL: `${url}` }
```

to the initiated class, so the class `Request` would now look like this:

```
  {
    httpsProxy: (process.env.HTTPS_PROXY ? process.env.HTTPS_PROXY : ''),
    retryOptions: {
      retries: 0,
      retryableMethods: ['GET', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
      statusShouldRetry: (status) => (status >= 500) && (status <= 599),
    },
    timeout: 100000,
    baseURL: 'https://url.com',
    headers: {'X-API-Key': abc }
  }
```

Is there a good/better way of doing what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: You mean you want to customise the instance of the class, not the class itself?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I more the instance I am creating, not the actual class, sorry for not making that clear.

Comment: By using the spread syntax, you lost the prototype and all the methods of the object. Also it looks like you're trying to modify the options object that is getting passed to `new Request` as an argument, not the object itself.

Comment: Why not just move the `new Request(…)` inside the `jenkinsServicesDevAxway`? You want to return a different object from each `jenkinsServicesDevAxway()` call anyway, no?

Comment: Good question there is going to be multiple `jenkinsServicesDevAxway`. Like 10-15. All of them are going to use the same information as `requestBaseConnection` so I didn't want to duplicate and repeat code, instead reference it once the add to it in each request.

Comment: You can reuse the options, yeah, why not. But I don't think you can (or should) reuse the whole `Request` instance.

Comment: Okay, and how would I just reuse the options part of the Class? I am fully on-board to do this another way, what's the best way to re-use and reference without reusing the whole Class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like

```
const Request = require('my-library');

const baseRequestOptions = {
  httpsProxy: (process.env.HTTPS_PROXY ? process.env.HTTPS_PROXY : ''),
  retryOptions: {
    retries: 0,
    retryableMethods: ['GET', 'HEAD', 'OPTIONS', 'PUT', 'DELETE'],
    statusShouldRetry: (status) => (status >= 500) && (status <= 599),
  },
  timeout: 100000,
};

function jenkinsServicesDevAxway(token, url) {
  return new Request({
    ...baseRequestOptions,
    headers: {
      'X-API-Key': token
    },
    baseURL: url,
  });
}

module.exports = {
  jenkinsServicesDevAxway
};

// …
jenkinsServicesDevAxway('abc', 'https://url.com');
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but I don't think that is working, this is my response from jenkinsServicesDevAxway;

```
function wrap() {
    var args = new Array(arguments.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
      args[i] = arguments[i];
    }
    return fn.apply(thisArg, args);
  }
```

Comment: @user3180997 I have no idea where that `function wrap` is coming from, maybe it's inside `my-library`?

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought, I am checking that now, the moment I get it working I will let you know and make the answer as correct.